# How to find out file size in Node?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I have an app to deduce the size of a file uploaded by the user. I have the code as follows

The server.js code is as follows

```
var express = require('express');
var formidable = require('express-formidable');
var fs = require('fs');

var app = express();

var PORT = 8080;

app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views'));

app.use(formidable.parse());

app.set('views', './views');

app.set('view engine', 'jade');

app.get('/', function(req, res){
   res.render('index.jade'); 
});
```

When I try to log the variable stats below, I get an error saying

> TypeError: path must be a string

```
app.post('/upload', function(req, res){
   var stats = fs.statSync(req.body);
   console.log(stats);
});

app.listen(PORT, function(){
    console.log('Express listening on port: '+PORT);
});
```

The index.jade file is rendered below

```
html
    head
        link(rel='stylesheet', href='style.css', type='text/css')
        title Upload file for shortening
    body
        h1 Welcome to file metadata service
        div(id='upload-button')
            form(action='/upload', enctype='multipart/form-data')
                input(name='Upload', type='file', id='upload-butt')
        div(id="submit-button")
            form(action = '/submit')
                button(type="submit", value='Submit', id='submit-butt') Submit

        script(src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js")
        script(src="upload.js")
```

The css styling is below

```
#submit-butt{
    width:100px;
    height:auto;
    background-color:red;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:150px;
}

#upload-butt{
    width:200px;
    height:auto;
    cursor:pointer;
    float:left;
}

h1{
    font-family:Impact;
}
```

The jQuery code is given below

```
$('#upload-butt').on('click', function(){
   $('#upload-butt').on('change', function(){
      var file = $(this).get(0).files;

      if(file.length > 0){
          var formData = new FormData();
          formData.append('Upload', file, file.name);
          $.ajax({
              url: '/upload', 
              type: 'POST',
              data:formData,
              processData:false,
              contentType:false,
              success: function(data){
                  console.log('upload successful: '+data);
              }
          })
      }
   });
});
```

How do I deal with the TypeError? How do I convert the path to a string? What I have is the parsed data obtained after running through formidable middleware.

Comment: What is the value of req.body for the upload endpoint?

Comment: req.body is likely an object, fs is looking for a path string

Comment: @bmartin - When i try to log req.body, all I get is the object 
{Upload: ' '}

Comment: @VinnieJames - Yeah, I know. My question is how do I convert that to the file path?

Comment: you can check the size of the file in front end only. You can do it even before uploading the file. Just use "*.size" parameter. e.g. var size = file.size;

Comment: There is no file path in req.body. Based on your comment above all you could get is req.body.Upload which would return an empty string ''

Comment: @AmanDwivedi - I'm trying to return the file size on the server. How can I do that if I don't send in the FormData object and check that for file size?

Comment: @VinnieJames - Does that mean there is an error in the way I'm implementing express-formidable?

Comment: @ZaidHumayun In order to use fs.statSync you are going to need to upload the file to the server, then use a path to the file.

Answer (score 0):

Change the '/upload' in backend to this code. Don't use req parameters in that. No need of that.

```
    app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

  // create an incoming form object
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  // specify that we want to allow the user to upload multiple files in a single request
  form.multiples = true;

  // store all uploads in the /uploads directory
  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

  // every time a file has been uploaded successfully,
  // rename it to it's orignal name
  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
  });

  // log any errors that occur
  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  // once all the files have been uploaded, send a response to the client
  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('success');
  });

  // parse the incoming request containing the form data
  form.parse(req);

});
```

Comment: I get this error when I try this. 

TypeError: formidable.IncomingForm is not a function

Comment: var formidable = require('formidable');var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(); Check both the things

Comment: Hey, thanks! I had to use the formidable module, not the express-formidable module. Thanks for that! Any idea on how to use this to get the file size? I can't see a path field anywhere, so I assume I can't use the fs module here

Comment: you can get the file size from the front-end itself. Even if you want to do it in nodejs, you can use fs.statSync(filename). You already have the path, it is in /uploads folder and filename is also specified in file.name :) Give it a try.

Comment: Yeah, I tried that 
form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.rename(file.path, path.join(form.uploadDir, file.name));
    console.log('in here');
    console.log(fs.statSync(file.name));
  });

That doesn't seem to be working. The callback function isn't being entered because nothing is being logged.